# How to set the value of an MUI Autocomplete menu inside a react-hook-form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui, react-hook-form

I've inherited some code that uses MUI v5 controls in a form created with `react-hook-form` v6.  There are some autocomplete controls where I want the selection in one control to update the value of another (as a default; the user can always change it).

Listening to the autocomplete changes with `watch()` and then calling `setValue()` on another control works to update the form data, but the `inputValue` of the autocomplete widget doesn't visibly update.  So as far as the user can see, nothing has changed in the second autocomplete, even though the data that's returned in `onSubmit()` has been updated.

I've tried passing `inputValue` as a prop to the `<Autocomplete>`, but since it's being controlled by `react-hook-form`, that generates an error about the control being changed from uncontrolled to controlled.

[This codesandbox demonstrates the issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-autocomplete-in-react-hook-form-28oq0?file=/demo.js).  Selecting `"first"` in the `thing1` autocomplete should update `thing2` to `"last"`.  If you click *Submit*, the form's data will be logged to the console, showing that `thing2` has indeed been updated.  But the visible UI doesn't change.

[image: broken UI]

### Update

As so often happens when trying to explain a bug, a solution occurred to me.  I tried calling `register()` with a different name on the `<Autocomplete>`.  This caused the second autocomplete to update correctly when `setValue()` was called, but added some unnecessary fields to the submit data.  Then I removed the `register()` call entirely (which had already been there when I started looking at the code).  I guess registering a component if it's already a child of a `<Controller>` is unnecessary, and maybe confuses things.  (Maybe the library should throw an error in that case?)

The working custom component that wraps the `<Autocomplete>` in a `<Controller>` looks like this:

```js
const ControlledAC = ({ name, control, register, options }) => (
  <Controller
    name={name}
    control={control}
    render={(props) => (
      <Autocomplete
        {...props}
        freeSolo
        autoSelect
        options={options}
        onChange={(_, value) => props.onChange(value)}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label={name} />}
      />
    )}
  />
);
```

This interaction between MUI and `react-hook-form` seems a bit magical, though.  **Is this the right away to programmatically set a value on an `<Autocomplete>` component?**